# fabric.js mouseover & mouseout events on element in group not firing (mousedown & mouseup do fire)

Tags: events, canvas, mouseevent, fabricjs

I have a fabric.Group to which I added a couple of fabric.Rect via group.AddWithUpdate(). (All are displayed correctly in my canvas.) Tested on latest chrome and firefox.

this event doesn't fire (same with 'mouseout'):

```
rect.on('mouseover', function () {
    console.log('mouseover');
});
```

yet this event DOES fire (same with 'mouseup'):

```
rect.on('mousedown', function () {
    console.log('mousedown');
});
```

As per http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2#events and https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-events, it should work though.

my group and rect code:

```
var buttonsGroup = new fabric.Group([], {
    left: 0,
    top: 55,
    selectable: false,
    hoverCursor: 'auto',
    subTargetCheck: true,
    myID: 'group_menubuttons'
});

var menuButton = new fabric.Rect({
    left: buttonPosX,
    top: buttonPosY,
    width: buttonSize.width,
    height: buttonSize.height,
    fill: '#FFF',
    hoverCursor: 'pointer',
    hasControls: false,
    myClass: 'menuButton',
    myID: 'menuButton_' + type
});
```

Is my assumption, that all mouse events should fire on the element itself (instead of events on canvas or groups), wrong?
I hope I provided enough information and a clear problem. Help appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a complete fiddle with your code? Are you sure you wrote the events correctly? They are "mouse:down", "mouse:move", "mouse:up" and so on.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, @AlexIonescu. yes, I am sure. see the docs:

"For convenience, Fabric takes event system even further, and allows you to attach listeners directly to canvas objects. [...] We're attaching event listeners directly to rectangle and circle instances. Instead of "object:selected", we're using "selected" event."


(also, 'mousedown' is working perfectly and confirms that part in the docs.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly mouseUp, mouseDown events are for now the only one supported inside groups.

is not hard to support over and out, you can open an issue on the github issue tracker giving an use case